# Google account password reset

Tags: youtube, google-account

Everyone knows Google linked everything in one account. YouTube, Gmail, etc.

I'm trying to recover my YouTube account but it send me to my Google account so I don't remember that password. I go to the options that help me get it but the options there are truly useless as I do not remember when was the last time I used it because I only use YouTube (never my Google account) neither when I created it because I had that YouTube account for a long time and suddenly there were some emails about some merging between this two accounts.

Can't Google just send me a recovery password/code to the my email? I will be the only one supposed to see it.

Comment: nope apparently the information I provide is not enough, but what i don't understand is why they don't send me a code to my personal email to change my password if I don't provide the enough information they need(questions are really vague) how else am I supposed to answer their questions?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a recovery email, you can just click 'forgot password' and then enter the information. The google server will send you a password  **reset link**  to your recovery email. Hopefully, you know the password to your recovery email...